# HIVE Query for Array Sum

Tags: arrays, hive, sum, hiveql

I have a query as below. `Select split(Salary, '\|') as salaryEmp from tableA` and it works fine and gives me a an array string as `["1089","1078"]`.

I would want to add the values of this array string. I am not able to type cast it to integer and sum them. Can a suitable way be suggested for this.

Comment: How did you get to a situation where Salary(?!) is presented as a delimited string?

Comment: `'\|'` is wrong, should be `'\\|'`

Answer (score 1):

Use `explode()` + `lateral view`:

```
select sum(cast(salary as int)) sum_salry from
 (
 select split('1089|1078', '\\|') SalaryArray 
 ) s lateral view explode (SalaryArray) a as Salary;

OK
2167
```

Comment: Way too complicated...Can be done with a single `SELECT`

Answer (score 1):

```
select  sum(e.col) as sum_Salary
from    salaryEmp lateral view explode (split(Salary,'\\|')) e
```

---

```
+------------+
| sum_salary |
+------------+
|       2167 |
+------------+
```