# Find Max value from a list in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I need to find max value from a list in HIVE.

For eg:
If i am having values 
[5,4,3] in a list i need to get 5.

max(list_name) is not working.
Is there any workaround.

Comment: Can you show how have you tried to use `max`?

Comment: This looks similar: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43650849/2700344

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might not be the most optimized, but it kinda works.

```
 select max(arr) from ( select explode( array(4, 5, 1, 20, 45, 47, 9) ) as arr ) t

+------+--+
| _c0  |
+------+--+
|  47  |
+------+--+
```

Answer (score 2):

you can see this [doc](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+LateralView)

In your situation, if you have a table name `example`

```
| id | arr   |
| 1  | [1,2] |
| 2  | [3,4] |
```

if you want to get the result of

```
| id | max_arr|
| 1  |  2     |
| 2  |  4     |
```

try this `SQL`

```
SELECT id, max(arr_val) as max_arr FROM example LATERAL VIEW explode(arr) arrtable AS arr_val group by id
```

There are only one problem, your `id` must be unique.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following for min/max of an array:

```
SELECT sort_array(arr)[0] as min_arr,
sort_array(arr)[size(arr)-1] as max_arr,
FROM example;
```

In all the cases that I am aware of, this is more performant than a lateral view explode and group.

But I don't understand why there is no `min_array(arr)`.

Answer (score 0):

For my environment, the `sort_array` function will change the original array content. This may cause some unwanted results if you want to reuse the array.

You can use `greatest(a[0], a[1], a[2])` to find the max element. Moreover, use a `case when` clause if you want to find its index.