# SQL/Hive - How to parse and sum all values within a row

Tags: sql, arrays, hive

In my table, there is a column where each row contains a list of n values in the following format:
["5","12","13"]. This is a string

Is there a way for me to sum up all the values within this list? In this example, I would expect the returned value to be 30

I have tried using a string of replace functions to remove the brackets and quotes, and tried to use a split on the commas in order to sum it up but it does not appear to be working. I only have read access to this db. Any help would be appreciated, thank you

Comment: Does this question help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43649435/hive-query-for-array-sum

Comment: The first question, why would your column consist of a list of values???

Comment: Unfortunately the values are recognized as a string rather than an array, so explode doesn't seem to work. As for why the column consists of a list of values I have no idea, just have to work with this table

Answer (score 0):

If your column is of STRING data type then you can remove square brackets and double quotes using regexp_replace and split resulted string to get an array using split():

```
select sum(cast(element as int)) as mysum,
       --other columnt from t
    from mytable t
    lateral view outer explode(split(regexp_replace(col_name,'\\[|\\]|"',''),', *')) e as element
      --group by other columns from t
```

If it is `ARRAY<STRING>` then

```
select sum(cast(element as int)) as mysum,
       --other columnt from t
    from mytable t
    lateral view outer explode(col_name) e as element
      --group by other columns from t
```